How can I relate models with sequelize in express
I am not being able to make an association between my models, I am using postman to consult a specific provider, for example: Get in http://localhost:3000/api/proveedores/1
My relationship is one to one. In my database I have a related user and provider. I attach my models, controller, my index file in /models.
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { sequelize } = require('../config/db');
const Proveedor = require('./proveedor');

const Usuario = sequelize.define('Usuario', {
 idUsuario: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
 },
 nombreCompleto: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 usuario: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 contraseña: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 tipoUsuario: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: false,
 },
}, {
 tableName: 'Usuario'
});

Usuario.associate = (models) => {
 Usuario.hasOne(models.Proveedor, {foreignKey: 'Usuario_idUsuario'});
};

module.exports = Usuario;

const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { sequelize } = require('../config/db');
const Usuario = require('./Usuario.js');

const Proveedor = sequelize.define('Proveedor', {
 idProveedor: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
 },
 Usuario_idUsuario: {
   type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   allowNull: false,
   references: {
     model: Usuario,
     key: 'idUsuario'
   }
 },
 ruc: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(11),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 razonSocial: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 direccion: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(80),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 distrito: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 provincia: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: false,
 },
 departamento: {
   type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
   allowNull: true,
 },
}, {
 tableName: 'Proveedor'
});

Proveedor.associate = (models) => {
 Proveedor.belongsTo(models.Usuario, {foreignKey: 'Usuario_idUsuario'});
};

module.exports = Proveedor;

const { Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db').sequelize;

const Usuario = require('./Usuario.js');
const Proveedor = require('./proveedor');
const Empresa = require('./empresa');
const Material = require('./material');
const Compra = require('./compra');
const DetalleCompra = require('./detallecompra');

const db = {
  sequelize,
  Sequelize,
  Usuario,
  Proveedor,
  Empresa,
  Material,
  Compra,
  DetalleCompra,
};

// Aplicar las asociaciones
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

module.exports = db;


exports.getProveedorById = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  try {
    console.log(`Buscando proveedor con ID: ${id}`); // Registro de depuración

    const proveedor = await Proveedor.findByPk(id, {
      include: {
        model: Usuario,
        // as: 'usuario', // Asegúrate de que este alias coincida con la asociación en los modelos
        // attributes: ['nombreCompleto', 'usuario']
      }
    });

    if (!proveedor) {
      console.log(`Proveedor con ID: ${id} no encontrado`); // Registro de depuración
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Proveedor no encontrado' });
    }

    res.status(200).json(proveedor);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener el proveedor:', error); // Registro de depuración
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al obtener el proveedor', details: error.message });
  }
};




Try not to import models in each other modules and use a string notation to indicate a model in references
